# Easier way to set up external POP3 accounts in Gmail?

Tags: gmail, webmail

Gmail lets you use other POP3 email accounts. Setting them up isn't too hard, but it does involve a few steps.

Is there an easier way?

I know many hosting providers offer 1 click configuration scripts for desktop mail clients (For example, my host offers "one click" files for Mac Mail app (on iOS and Mac), Windows Live Mail and Microsoft Outlook).

Is there anything similar that can be used with Gmail?

I know you can forward email to a Gmail address, but then you can't reply with the original email address.

Comment: Of course you can reply with the original email address. You just need to set up the sending email address in "Accounts and Import".

Comment: But is there a one click solution to do this? As noted in my question, the method does involve a few steps.

Comment: Not within Gmail. If it exists, it'll be by some third-party.